# Spring Value: incorrect shows fields

Tags: java, spring

I withdraw all data to properties, for example:

```
email.content.charset=utf-8
```

I created a class with all properties, ResourcesProperties, in which I have this field & getter:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Value("${email.content.charset}")
    private String emailCharset;

    public String getEmailCharset() {
        return emailCharset;
    }
}
```

Spring scans this property file:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:/properties/mail.properties"})
```

It autowires into class I need:

```
@Autowired
private ResourcesProperties properties;
```

I try to show it:

```
System.out.println(properties.getEmailCharset());
```

Result:

```
${email.content.charset}
```

Do same via Environment:

```
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("email.content.charset"));
```

Result:

```
utf-8
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean

```
 @Bean
 public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
     return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```